# PyQt5 on Windows in Python 2.7: Error importing QtWidgets

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt5

I downloaded PyQt5 executable file on Windows 7 for python 2.7 both 64bit versions.

Is installed on C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5

I'm trying to use the above code:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QDialog
```

I get the error:

```
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I found the QtWidgets on this folder: `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\sip\PyQt5\QtWidgets`

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that you installed a version of PyQt5 that is compatible with your version of Python (32-bit or 64-bit)?

Comment: You are right! PyQt5 is incompatible with Python 2.7. It's only compatible with Python 3.4. I downloaded PyQt4 and it's working properly! Thank you for your reply!